# how to show error message on form validation when moving to one input to another input

Tags: forms, angular, ionic2

Take a look at my updated code

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label primary floating>
        USER ID (PHONE NO)
      </ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" id="useridphone" class="form-control" formControlName="useridphone"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.useridphone.errors && myForm.controls.useridphone.dirty " >
      <small class="up" > 
        <strong><i>
          Phone Number Must be 10 digits!
        </i></strong>
      </small>
    </p>
```

this below input box shows when ever user touch that field.

I want to show the error message in  this input field after user is moved to next input box.

but now when ever user touch the input field itself i am getting this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using **required** in `<ion-input>`?

E.g.

```
<ion-input type="number" id="useridphone" class="form-control" formControlName="useridphone" required></ion-input>
```

Not tested entirely though.